# Reading Guitar tab

Tags: guitar, tablature

Please tell me how to read this tab and play that melody. How I must use D5 chord in this tab and what are these strings to hit them at the same time?

Video link:

Tab link:
https://www.licknriff.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Everything-I-Do.jpg

https://www.licknriff.com/2015/02/everything-i-do/

Comment: Do you already know how to read normal, professionally printed tab? This tab looks pretty rough and hard to read. If this is your first attempt at reading tab, I would say you should pick a different tab to get started on.

Comment: The guy in the video explains it all quite well. what more information are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This tab is *very* rough-looking, but if you need to read it, it is manageable.

The tab is laid out as follows:

```
     D5   ...  G
e|---5----...----
B|---3----...--3-
G|---2----...--0-
D|---0----...--0-
A|--------...----
E|--------...--3-
```

**Strings are labelled assuming this is in standard tuning, I did not watch the video**

The following holds true regardless of tuning:

The bass strings (`EAD`) are at the bottom and the high strings (`GBe`) are at the top of the tab, as is standard. This is how the guitar's strings look when you are looking down at them.

The blank strings are strings that are not to be played.

In regular tablature, they can be left blank as seen here. Alternatively, they can be marked with an `x` to show that they are not to be played. Be careful, however, as the `x` could also mean the string is meant to be played percussively (ie, muted with your fretting fingers/picking hand). For this distinction, refer to the notation of the tab itself, as this may vary.

When notes are laid out in a line as above, they are all to be sounded at the same time. So in these cases you would pluck the `DGBe` or `EDGB` strings all at the same time (producing the `D5` chord or the `G` chord respectively).

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: mostly agree with this, however I think the wording about the X muting a string is a little confusing, as sometimes you will deliberately want to play a mute note, and other times you would want to play anything on that string at that time.

Comment: Good point, I never thought about playing strings percussively as is sometimes the case. I will edit the post to reflect this